# How resource effective in Java Executor framework

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I am using the java executor service to create the threadPool. The Job of each thread is identical and polls the status of the external task and Each thread has sleeping time. Let's say the size of the thread pool is N, Out N, K threads are currently engaged and CPU utilization has reached the maximum, for the K+1 thread doesn't have resource availability. Threads that are in sleeping mode, would reduce the CPU utilization and do the other threads have the resource availability?

Comment: Probably... but it depends... are the external tasks on different machines? Then your threads are I/O bound and shouldn't consume CPU while doing network I/O, and a different number of threads won't change CPU use. So what is your real question? How to reduce CPU load? IMHO your question needs more details; see [ask].

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes! External tasks are in different machine My Threads make a network I/O, Thread will assigned to the task only after a new event was raised. if more events are arrived then my tasks are queued-up! My Question here is - if I have better delay strategy does it reduce the CPU utilization ? So I can define optimum pool size

Answer (score 1):

Putting your threads to sleep will probably reduce the CPU utilization, but since in the executor framework a `ThreadPoolExecutor` does not implement a work-stealing algorithm, once the `MaximumPoolSize` threshold has been reached with every thread busy in a task, it doesn't matter whether they're sleeping or not, those threads have already committed to those tasks and they will keep executing them until their termination (abruptly or with success). This means that they won't release the sleeping tasks in favor of the ones queuing up and ready to be executed.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

However, since in your question you mentioned

> The Job of each thread is identical and **polls the status** of the external task and Each thread has sleeping time.

It sounds like you need to check whether a particular event has occurred every *x* seconds. To optimize the execution, you could use a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` instead, where n `Runnable` are scheduled with the `scheduleWithFixedDelay` method to check every *x* seconds if the particular condition is met.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

Here is a rough implementation with a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` where each task identified with an id checks every *x* seconds for a particular condition to happen (the creation of a folder with their same id).

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor pool = (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
        int numTasks = 16;

        //ConcurrentHashMap shared among the submitted tasks where each Task updates its corresponding outcome to true as soon as the folder has been created
        ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Boolean> mapResult = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numTasks; i++) {
            mapResult.put(i, false);
        }

        //Scheduling each tasks and keeping the ScheduledFuture returned by each submitted task in a local Map
        ScheduledFuture<?> schedFut;
        Map<Integer, ScheduledFuture<?>> mapTasks = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numTasks; i++) {
            schedFut = pool.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new MyTask(i, mapResult), i * 20, 3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            mapTasks.put(i, schedFut);
        }

        //Checking whether all the tasks have completed their verification
        while (!mapTasks.values().stream().allMatch(v -> v.isCancelled())) {
            for (Integer key : mapTasks.keySet()) {
                //Canceling the i-th task scheduling if:
                //  - Its result is positive (i.e. its verification is terminated)
                //  - The task hasn't been canceled already
                if (mapResult.get(key) && !mapTasks.get(key).isCancelled()) {
                    schedFut = mapTasks.get(key);
                    schedFut.cancel(true);
                }
            }

            //... eventually adding a sleep to check whether the tasks have completed every x seconds ...
        }

        pool.shutdown();
    }
}

class MyTask implements Runnable {
    private int num;
    private ConcurrentHashMap mapRes;

    public MyTask(int num, ConcurrentHashMap mapRes) {
        this.num = num;
        this.mapRes = mapRes;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Task " + num + " is checking whether the folder exists: " + Files.exists(Path.of("./" + num)));
        if (Files.exists(Path.of("./" + num))) {
            mapRes.replace(num, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dan, Thanks for your reply! My requirement is slightly different. I only initiate a task depends on the another event.  Each Task involve N/W IO. So I am planning to use ThreadPoolExecutor with keepAliveTime. Tx